# Save reference to interface callback in DialogFragment after configurationChange

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, savestate, onconfigurationchanged

I have an Activity that host a Fragment. In that Fragment I open a DialogFragment.

In the Fragment I call this function to show the dialog. Note that before showing the dialog I set an Interface defined in the DialogFragment.

```
private void showRatingDialog(){

        if (getActivity() != null) return;

        MyRatingDialog ratingDialog = new MyRatingDialog();
        ratingDialog.setOnRatingDialog(new MyRatingDialog.OnRatingDialog() {
            // some code
        });

        ratingDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), MyRatingDialog.TAG);        

}
```

My MyRatingDialog class:

```
public class MyRatingDialog extends DialogFragment{

    private OnRatingDialog onRatingDialog;

    public interface OnRatingDialog{
        void onSubmitRating(int rateSelected);
        void onCancelRating();
    }

    public void setOnRatingDialog(OnRatingDialog onRatingDialog) {
        this.onRatingDialog = onRatingDialog;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_rating, null, false);

        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(layout).create();
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

        ratingStarComponent = (RatingStarComponent)layout.findViewById(R.id.rating_star_component);
        ratingStarComponent.setOnRateListener(new RatingStarComponent.OnRateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRateClickListener(int starRate) {
                rate = starRate;
            }
        });

        Button rateButton = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        rateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (onRatingDialog!=null) { // this is null after a configuration change
                    onRatingDialog.onSubmitRating(rate, optionsSelected, commentsEditText.getText().toString());
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        ImageView closeButton = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.close);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        return alertDialog;


    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);

        onRatingDialog.onCancelRating();

    }

}
```

The problem is that after a configurationChange like screen rotation or any other configurationChange, the interface onRatingDialog is null.
My question is what is the best way/best practice to save the reference to onRatingDialog interface after a configurationChange?
I wouldn't like to make the hosted Activity implements the interface, as I think it's more complex access to the dialog.
By doing setRetainInstance(true) the dialog is closed after the configurationChange, so how can I mantain the dialog visible keeping the reference to the interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check out [fragments doc.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

find the below code on the page to implement a listener, Your Activity must implement the Listener you created in dialog.
Then the Activity will be notified from dialogFragment and notify the concerned fragment from Activity.

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;
...
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
    }
}
...
```

You can also download the sample project [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Sorry but this doesnt answer my question. I wanted to avoid implementing the interface by the host activity to make it easier. I just want to know if there is a way to keep the reference to the listener from the DialogFragment when a configurationChanges occurs. Thanks

Comment: i guess the answer is no...because this is the only correct and bug free way to implement fragments.